# Move batch file until an specific date

Tags: batch

Hello guys I have the following batch file to move files from "current" folder to "archive folder". this task runs every other week.

```
// Move files from Current folder to Archive folder using a batch file
@echo off
move "M:\systems\main\data\panelData\current\*.*" "M:\systems\main\data\panelData\archive\"
```

however, I would like to keep the current day files in "current folder" and just move the files to archive files that were used from day before and so on.

i.e ( if the batch file runs today 15th of October, will be move all files until the 14th of October)

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `forfiles` to call the command separately for each file older than X days:

```
forfiles /p M:\systems\main\data\panelData /m current* /d -2
```

Once you've verified that this returns correct results, add `/c` to make it actually move the files:

```
forfiles ... /c "cmd /c move @file M:\systems\main\data\panelData\archive"
```

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles
- https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: mmm what does mean /p? and /m?. Sorry I am not related to batch files this is the first batch file I have done.

Comment: it worked! thanks!

Comment: @MatiasSquartini: The options are documented in `forfiles /?` as well as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) or [here](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html). If this is the first script, though, I'd recommend to not actually start with batch scripts at all, and to go straight towards writing PowerShell instead...

Answer (score 0):

> - ***`ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html`***:
>
>
>   ```bat
>   There are some disadvantages to using CMD.exe with FORFILES, a
>   new process will be created and destroyed for every file that
>   FORFILES you loop through 1000 files, then 1000 copies of
>   CMD.exe will be closed, this will affect performance. Also
>   any variable created with SET will be lost as soon as
>   FORFILES moves on to the next file.
>   ```

---

> *however, I would like to keep the current day files in "current folder" and just move the files to archive files that were used from day before and so on.*
>
> *i.e (if the batch file runs today 15th of October, will be move all files until the 14th of October)*
>
> *how can I do that?*
>
> - Try **[`RoboCopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)** instead use `[`**[`ForFile`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)`+`[`CMD.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**`]`:
> - Use: [`RoboCopy ... /MinAge:2`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

---

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData" || Exit /b %ErrorLevel%
set "_dest=M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData\Archive"

robocopy .\. "%_dest%" /Mov  /MinAge:2 /CopyAll /R:2 /W:10 /XF *.cmd /NJH /NJS /S
```

---

- **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```bat
$SourceDir='M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData'
$TargetDir='M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse | Where-Object { 
    $_.CreationDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) 
  } | Move-Item –Force -Verbose -Destination $TargetDir -Whatif

# Or...

$SourceDir='M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData'
$TargetDir='M:\Systems\Main\Data\PanelData\Archive'

ls -Path $SourceDir -Re | ? { 
    $_.CreationDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) 
  } | Mv –Fo -Verb -Dest $TargetDir -Wi
```

---